# I can see this deleted question even though I don't have 10k?

Tags: discussion, support, bug

Title pretty much sums it up. I am somehow able to view [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/745876/wireless-adapter-issues-with-qualcomm-atheros-168c0042-rev-30/745887#745887) even though I don't have 10k reputation.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've answered the question. As you're allowed to see your own deleted posts, you must also be allowed to see any parent posts of said deleted posts.

In other words, you can see your answer. Which means you can see the question that you answered.

This is intentional behavior.